# Using SQL Server : how to use select criteria based on sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the below table and using SQL (SQL Server preferred), how can I select only the ProductID's that sum to the first 200 orders or less is returned?

In other words, I'd like ID's for 'Corn Flakes', 'Wheeties' returned since this is close to the sum of 200 orders but returning anything more would be over the limit.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions. 
Asking something like "I want to do xyz" with no trace of effort or info about the errors you got is likely to be closed due to lack of info to answer. 
This is not a "write my code" service.
Remember to add all the relevant code, error logs and everything in your question as plain text, so we can provide better help. :)

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: I using MS SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that 108 + 92 = 200, I must assume that you want the product ids in order.

In that case, you can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(orders) over (order by product_id) as running_orders
      from t
     ) t
where running_orders <= 200;
```

Comment: I just looked it up and learned about sum over (order by | partition). Is as simple as:


select ProductID, ProductName, sum(Orders) over (order by  ProductID)
from #temp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which is more appropriate for your level and version:

```
select * from T as t
where (
    select sum(Orders) from T as t2
    where t2.ProductID <= t.ProductID -- *
) <= 200;

with data as (
    select *,
        sum(Orders)
            over (order by ProductID desc) as cumm -- *
    from T
)
select * from data where cumm <= 200;
```

Both of these essentially assume there will be no ties, or at least no ties that would both land as a single product order in the 200th spot.

If you discover that you intended to sort by number or orders rather than product id change the column references in the lines marked with asterisks.